# SoftLayer API Hardware : Network (VLAN) Details during Provision of BareMetal Server

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Provision of BareMetal Servers:

Using the below mentioned blog, I am able to provision hourly bare metal server.

http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/ordering-bare-metal-servers-using-softlayer-api

But I am unable to set VLAN details in the request object. If I pass VLAN details in the payload I am getting error message as:

```
"error":"VLANs may not be specified for Bare Metal Server configurations.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}.
```

Also I want to know whether I can set private only network flag as true?

Answer (score 0):

It would be great to see your payload, but the configuration of VLANs is here http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware/createObject,

your payload should be something loke this:

```
hw = {
    'datacenter': {'name': 'tor01'},
    'hostname': 'simplebmi',
    'domain': 'test.com',
    'hourlyBillingFlag': True,
    'fixedConfigurationPreset': {'keyName': 'S1270_8GB_2X1TBSATA_NORAID'},
    'networkComponents': [{
        'maxSpeed': 1000,
    }],
    'operatingSystemReferenceCode': 'UBUNTU_14_64',
     "primaryNetworkComponent": { 
        "networkVlan": { 
            "id": 52123
        } 
    }, 
   "primaryBackendNetworkComponent": { 
        "networkVlan": { 
            "id": 2 
        } 
    } 
}
```

and yes you can set the private only network just add this to the payload:

```
"privateNetworkOnlyFlag": true
```

Regards

Comment: @nessus I am using the similar payload which you have shared and it's not working. we are getting valid error message as  : "error":"VLANs may not be specified for Bare Metal Server configurations.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"                                    I think SL is not allowing configuration of VLANs for BM Server as per error message. If we use "privateNetworkOnlyFlag" : true it's working and only private VLAN is created for BM Server and no public VLAN.

Comment: Oh I see what happened, before the method used the package 50 to create the Server, now they change it to the package 200. The package 200 is for fast provisioning and it does not allow to configure the VLANs. So if you need to create the server and configure the VLANs you need to use this method http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder here is some documentation how to use the method in Python http://sldn.softlayer.com/es/blog/bpotter/Going-Further-SoftLayer-API-Python-Client-Part-3

Comment: Just i want to order bare metal servers with OS and without OS using fast provision API. It would be great if SL provided VLAN configuration in fast provisioning for package 200. SoftLayer_Product_Package/getAllObjects in response we are getting package Id 50 for bare metal instance and package Id 200 for bare metal servers. Assume if we invoke getCategories on package 200 and filter for OS,Server details and after that get priceId and order bare metal servers it will work right.

Comment: As long as you set the correct pricesId in your order the placeOrder will work. But as you only need to create servers with OS and without OS regardless  the VLAN you can still use the Softlayer_Hardware::createObject method, just in case to get the valid list of OS and other configurations you can call http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware/getCreateObjectOptions

Comment: Just in case, even if you use the placeOrder method to order a server and you use the package 200 in the order, you will not able to set the VLANs, because the package do not allow such configuration, you need to pick out another package different from package 200.

Comment: If we select different package other than 200, is it will be bare metal server. As per  SoftLayer_Product_Package/getAllObjects in response we are getting package Id 50 for bare metal instance and package Id 200 for bare metal servers. In the response, there is no other package which shows it's bare metal server.

Comment: both 50 and 200 are for bare metal servers, but it seems the package 50 will be removed. Any way there are more packages for bare metal servers. Try this method http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package_Server/getAllObjects the package for bare metal server are the ones which  the "packageType" field is equals to BARE_METAL_CORE, BAREL_METAL_CPU and BARE_METAL_CPU_FAST_PROVISION